# Check if intersecting within a 1 "block" radius

Tags: c#

I have two positions on a 3D system, say [15, 32, 42] and [16, 32, 42]

Is there a easy way to check if they are within a 1 block radius from each other?

This is what I have, but is there a better way of doing it:

```
if (pos[0] == pos1[0] / 32 || pos[0] == pos1[0] + 1 || pos[0] == pos1[0] - 1)
{
    if (pos[1] == pos1[1] || pos[1] == pos1[1] - 1 || pos[1] == pos1[1] + 1)
    {
        if (pos[2] == pos1[2] || pos[2] == pos1[2] + 1 || pos[2] == pos1[2] - 1)
        {
```

Thanks,
David

Comment: Are the values in your 3D system always integers?  And would you consider [0,0,0] 1 *block* away from [1,1,1]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Math.abs(pos[0]-pos1[0]) <= 1` to check if two coordinates in the same plane are at most 1 apart.

So all in all, your code could look like this:

```
if( Math.abs(pos[0]-pos1[0]) <= 1 
    && Math.abs(pos[1]-pos1[1]) <= 1 
    && Math.abs(pos[2]-pos1[2]) <= 1 )
{
  Within a 1 block radius
}
```

Note that I do not understand why you divided your first equation by 32. I did not include that in this answer.

Note also that this solution makes things a little more readable, but that yours is correct too.

Comment: The Co-ordinates are Minecraft ones. Notch multiplied all positions by 32, but the information I have is already divided by 32 (as it is a byte).. How do I make this so it is divided by 32? Just do

    `if( Math.abs((pos[0] / 32)-(pos[0] / 32)) <= 1`?

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Yes. Or because `(x/32)-(y/32) = (x-y)/32`, you could also write the simpler `Math.abs(pos[0]-pos1[0]) <= 32`.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done this in c# but in Java I use JTS. http://geoapi.codeplex.com/ seems to provice the same functionality in c#. Then you will represent your points as Point objects and have all sorts of useful geospatial functions to use.

But for this case, are you looking for the "as the crow flies" distance, which is just pythagoras, or the "walking distance", which would involve finding the shortest valid route in a directed graph of footpaths?

Julian